# How to find mean of each two rows of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean

I have a big numpy array and want to take the mean of the second columns of each two rows and save the array as a new one. I want to take the mean of each two row, i.e. the mean of second column of of rows 1 and 2. Then, mean of second column of rows 3 and 4, and so on. Then, I want to merge each two rows as a single one. First and third columns of this paired rows are also the same. This is my simplified array:

```
input= np.array ([[1., 2., 5.],
                  [1., 4., 5.],
                  [4., 10., 3.],
                  [4., 2., 3.],
                  [1., 0., 0.],
                  [1., 1., 0.]])
```

Then, I want to get:

```
output= np.array ([[1., 3., 5.],
                   [4., 6., 3.],
                   [1., 0.5, 0.]])
```

I tried the following but it was not successful at all:

```
output=np.array([])
for i in range (len(input)-1):
    g=(input[i,1]+input[i+1,1])/2
    output=np.append(g,output)
```

In advance, I do appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two rows, I find it easier to do:

```
(arr[::2] + arr[1::2])/2
```

Answer (score 2):

A little more robust method for `reshape`, using the input shape

```
i= np.array ([[1., 2., 5.],
              [1., 4., 5.],
              [4., 10., 3.],
              [4., 2., 3.],
              [1., 0., 0.],
              [1., 1., 0.]])

i.reshape(-1, 2, i.shape[-1]).mean(1)

array([[1. , 3. , 5. ],
       [4. , 6. , 3. ],
       [1. , 0.5, 0. ]])
```

Comment: Dear @Daniel F, Thanks for the solution. It is exactly what I wanted. I do appreciate it.

Comment: Be sure to mark solved (the little checkmark) then.

Answer (score 1):

You could reshape and find the mean, as follows:

```
import numpy as np

ipt = np.array([[1., 2., 5.],
                [1., 4., 5.],
                [4., 10., 3.],
                [4., 2., 3.],
                [1., 0., 0.],
                [1., 1., 0.]])
result = np.mean(ipt.reshape((3, 2, 3)), axis=1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1.  3.  5. ]
 [4.  6.  3. ]
 [1.  0.5 0. ]]
```

As a side note, avoid using input as a variable name as it shadows the built-in input.

Comment: Dear Dani Mesejo, Thanks for devoting time to my problem. I do appreciate it. But, I colud not run your solution for my big array. I was giving me a reshape error.

Comment: You need to change the dimensions to fit it accordingly, in this regar the solution of @DanielF is better.

Answer (score 1):

Take even rows (`ipt[::2]`), odd rows (`ipt[1::2]`), add them and divide by 2:

```
output = (ipt[::2] + ipt[1::2])/2
```